# Disable preview secure text entry UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

When an entry is made in into an UITextField, that has secure text entry enabled.
The last character that is input is given a short preview for a second or so.

I want to disable that as well. Thus, as soon as a character is entered the black dot appears without the preview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished by configuring the field's UITextFieldDelegate like this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    textField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    return false
}
```